# Does long polling create new SignalR Hubs on each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

From the tutorials on SignalR I have learned that the Hub class works similarly to ASP WebForms pages. On each request a new Hub is created, processes the request, sends a response and is then destroyed. However, I am not quite sure whether I understand correctly, how it works with individual transport technologies. Please, correct me if I am wrong, but I assume the following:

Since WebSockets create a duplex channel, the connection is persisted until the client disconnects (or the connection is broken from a different reason) and a single instance of Hub services the client making the initial request.

However, in long polling, the Hub instance is destroyed as soon as the server sends a response. The SignalR client then automatically creates another request (as is the nature of polling). However, this request creates a brand new instance of Hub on the server, which is completely different from the Hub object servicing the first request. This second Hub instance then processes the request, sends a response and is destroyed. The client then sends a third request and the whole process starts again.

Am I right or am I wrong? I could not find the answer anywhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hubs are not created per connection, but per *relevant* request from client to server (I'm not discussing hub contexts created directly on the server side). Your statement *"a single instance of Hub services the client making the initial request"* about WebSocket is wrong.  When you start a connection on the client and the process succeeds, a hub is created to trigger the `OnConnected` event, *and then it's dropped*. When server side methods are called by a client, again a new hub is created *and then dropped* for each call. *This is true whatever transport you are using, including WebSocket*. A hub is **not** created to satisfy a physical connection per se, so long polling it's not an issue because it's no different from WebSocket. Each WebSocket connection or long polling HTTP request does not imply the creation of a *persistent* hub. Hubs are transient instances created upon each *logical* connections (*) *and* each method calls. Each time a connection event is triggered or method is called on a hub, there's a new instance answering, no matter the transport used.

[This](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) is probably the best piece of doc to check, but as soon as you start distinguishing logical level (SignalR events and method calls live there) from physical level (HTTP requests or WebSocket, which are not necessarily related to the logical level) then it should be clearer.

You can also verify it by yourself by just add something like this:

```
private readonly Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

to you hub, and you'll see that any `OnConnected` event and then any following method call would have different values for it *whatever transport you choose*, therefore proving that no 1 to 1 relationship ever exists between connection and hubs  (which does not mean that the underlying physical connection would not be preserved when possible, like with WebSocket).

(*) *there are subtleties here making this statement not always true, but they are not related to transport strategies so I'll skip them.*

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Didn't realize hubs were created for every invocation. You mentioned there are exceptions - could you elaborate?

Is there a way for hubs not to be transient? Thanks!

Comment: @CoderBang It's been a while since that reply, so I'm not sure anymore what I was thinking about :) Probably to the fact that, if you want, you could play with the internals of SignalR and change the hub creation strategy, therefore potentially introducing ways to cache instances, but I think that unless you don't really go there and hack the way things work out of the box then the prevalent behavior is the one described. If I meant something else I can't remember anymore.

Comment: The request pipeline is only created once for 
the lifetime of a websocket, but over and over for each long poll request. Keep in mind this is separate from the Hub itself, and may only affect you if you are doing something like a custom Middleware authentication module. Or if you use the context.environment, which is retained for a webrequest, but overwritten for each long poll.